# can't connect to MySQL remotely on Windows 10

Tags: mysql

I already edited my config,
`bind-address = 0.0.0.0` I also granted privileges on existing accounts to allow remote access, made sure I was connecting to `port: 3306`, I also allowed inbound and outbound connection of `port: 3306`.

I checked my MySQL status it says `connection: localhost via TCP/IP` and I still can't connect to my MySQL remotely. Any help? Thanks!

I'm running Windows 10

EDIT: I also check on netstat, port 3306 is running and listening. Also configured the "port forwarding" on my router (local IP:port 3306)

Comment: no, I forgot to mention I used netstat and saw port 3306 is listening

Comment: Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. This is the meaning of the error.

Comment: Like I said, I used `netstat` and got this result `Local address 0.0.0.0:3306`, what could be the problem?

Comment: So you must have used the wrong IP:port from the remote host.

Comment: I used my IP from https://www.whatsmyip.org/ which is my public IP address , but when I use my local IP (starts with 192.168) it works.

Comment: So you need to arrange port forwarding from your router to this host for 3306.

Comment: @user207421 Yeah, I configured my router to forward it to my internal IP, still no luck.